# How to randomize the seed of the "noise" library

Tags: python, python-2.7, perlin-noise, noise-generator

I want to create a 2D list of floats with Perlin Noise. I would like the values generated to be different every time I run the program. However, I'm not sure how to provide randomized seeds for the noise library I found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/caseman/noise).

*How can I make the program generate different values every time it's run?*

**My Code:**

```
from __future__ import division
import noise
import math
from singleton import ST


def create_map_list():
    """
    This creates a 2D list of floats using the noise library. It then assigns
    ST.map_list to the list created. The range of the floats inside the list
    is [0, 1].
    """

    # used to normalize noise to [0, 1]
    min_val = -math.sqrt(2) / 2
    max_val = abs(min_val)

    map_list = []

    for y in range(0, ST.MAP_HEIGHT):
        row = []

        for x in range(0, ST.MAP_WIDTH):
            nx = x / ST.MAP_WIDTH - 0.5
            ny = y / ST.MAP_HEIGHT - 0.5
            row.append((noise.pnoise2(nx, ny, 8) - min_val) / (max_val - min_val))

        map_list.append(row )

    ST.map_list = map_list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noise library do not support seed. At actual state, you cannot have random output.

But, one [pull request](https://github.com/caseman/noise/pull/22) has been posted to fix this point.

To do so, you will have to rebuild the library once you get the modified code. (`python setup.py install`)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do so is to add up a random number to `x` and `y` at the noise function, so you can use the `random.seed()`, too. I'm working on a Minecraft world generation project and I'm using noise.